# Lottie Animation is not working and Lottie callback Listener not called in Android

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout, lottie

I'm working on Lottie animation in android but Lottie animation callback function is not called.

XML file:

```
<com.airbnb.lottie.LottieAnimationView
    android:layout_width="@dimen/margin_15"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/margin_15"
    android:id="@+id/lav_LikeAnim"
    app:lottie_autoPlay="true"
    app:lottie_fileName="handshake_lottie.json"
    app:lottie_loop="false"
    android:visibility="gone"
    android:scaleX="2"
    android:scaleY="2"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    />
```

Code: After response of liked:

```
try {
    likeLottieAnim.playAnimation();
    likeLottieAnim.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    iv_like.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    tv_likes_count.setVisibility(View.GONE);
} catch (Exception exception) {
    exception.printStackTrace();
    Logger.i(TAG,"Lottie_animation_exception :"+exception);
}
```

Code: Callback : It's not called after lottieAnimation Play(likeLottieAnim.playAnimation()), I debug it but no succeed.

```
likeLottieAnim.addAnimatorListener(new Animator.AnimatorListener() {

    @Override
    public void onAnimationStart(Animator animation) {
        iv_like.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        tv_likes_count.setVisibility(View.GONE);

    }

    @Override
    public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
        try {
            iv_like.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            tv_likes_count.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            likeLottieAnim.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        } catch (Exception exception) {
            exception.printStackTrace();
            Logger.i(TAG,"Lottie_animation_exception :"+exception);
        }
        iv_like.setImageDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(context, R.drawable.ic_liked));

    }

    @Override
    public void onAnimationCancel(Animator animation) {
        Logger.i(TAG,"onAnimationCancel :");

    }

    @Override
    public void onAnimationRepeat(Animator animation) {
        Logger.i(TAG,"onAnimationRepeat :");

    }
});
```

where I made the mistake?

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this problem on the emulator. After searching for the reason, I see that an option called 'Remove Animations' is enabled in the accessibility of the emulator.

I have seen that if this option is enabled, Lottie Animation does not work and Lottie callback Listener is not called in the Android

[image: A screenshot has been taken from the emulator, which shows that the 'Remove Animations' option in accessibility has been enabled.]

Try disabling the 'Remove Animations' option in the accessibility of the emulator or your device.

Comment: thanks. my mistake in xml file, lottie define it under anpther LinearLayout. so it's not showing because of conditions.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry guys, I caught a mistake in XML file, Lottie define it under another Linearlayout. I changed the position and now it's fixed.